# pushViewController not working on iPad only

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tab bar view controller with a view controller member, which is embedded in a navigation view controller. In this view controller, I have a tableview, with a list of items. When you click on an item, you are directed to another view controller. Here is the code of the row that is selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print([indexPath.row])

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let sleepViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SleepItemEnter") as! SleepEnterTimesViewController

    sleepViewController.daySelected =  sleepList[indexPath.row].dayOfWeek
    sleepViewController.daySelectedInt =  indexPath.row

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sleepViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Now it has been working fine on all iPhones I tested. But now I tested it on iPad Pro and it doesn't work. The line "self.navigationController?.pushViewController" isn't working. The new view controller isn't showing at all.

Why would this be, only on iPad?

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` nil when run on the iPad?

Comment: Use the debugger or add a print statement.

Comment: I printed print(self.navigationController), and it was nil

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard, or atleast show how you've instantiated your `UITabBarController`, `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Can u try with Segue? It will be very useful.

Comment: @McDonal_11. I used segues and it worked. Don't know why